# How get last result with complex css selector?

Tags: css-selectors, jsoup

```html
<div id="container">
<p>
 <div>a</div>
 <div>b</div>
 <div><span>foo</span>c</div>
</p>
<p>
 <div>e</div>
 <div>f</div>
</p>
<p>
 <div>g</div>
 <div><span>foo</span>h</div>
 <div>i</div>
</p>
</div>
```

I would like to get last div which contains foo, ie div with h.

Online test : http://try.jsoup.org/~Ef0KHIiN77L_DANA7e4SpYZSVEM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with a selector alone. The best you can do is

```
#container div:has(span:containsOwn(foo))
```

but you'll still need to grab the last element separately using `.last()` after you run the selector.

Answer (score 1):

I would try this, but it is not a pure CSS solution, since you can't select easily the last element of a selection.

```
Element el = doc.select("div:contains(foo):not(:has(div))").last();
```

My selector selects all divs that contain "foo" but do not contain any other divs.